# sorting a column with rows

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a set of points (x,y,z). I want to sort these data using first column and 2nd and 3rd columns should be rearranged according to the sorting 1st column. is it possible to do this in c++, if so could you pls help me.

Herewith I am attaching codes of my implementation but I got a error message “invalid conversion from ‘const’ vod*’ to ‘const int [*][3]’ “ in line 31 and 32. I tried this using several methods but my effort was not success yet. I used here ‘qsort’ for this, are there any other methods or can I use ‘sort’ in  to do this. Since I have a very big data set I wish to use a fast method.
So what I need at the end the data set which is sorted using only 1st column like following example:
before sort

```
34  12  12
12  34 15
24  20  34
13  11  10
40  23  32
```

after sort

```
12  34 15
13  11  10
24  20  34
34  12  12
40  23  32
```

if any good methods help me to write codes …thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
   private:          
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

   public:
     Point(){};
     ~Point(){};

   Point(double X, double Y, double Z){
     x=X;y=Y;z=Z; }

   double X(){return x;}
   double Y(){return y;}
   double Z(){return z;}
};

int cmp ( const void *pa, const void *pb ) {
const int (*a)[3] = pa;
const int (*b)[3] = pb;
if ( (*a)[1] < (*b)[1] ) return -1;
if ( (*a)[1] > (*b)[1] ) return +1;
return 0;
}

int main ( ) {
vector<Point> points;
int input_x,input_y,input_z;       
   int i=0;
   while(i<6){//data set,it is a example, actual data come from a file 

         cout<<"x: ";cin>>input_x;
         cout<<"y: ";cin>>input_y;
         cout<<"z: ";cin>>input_z;
         Point point(input_x,input_y,input_z);                        
         points.push_back(point);
        i++;                         
         }        
for (int i=0;i<points.size();i++){//before sort
cout<<points[i].X()<<" "<<points[i].Y()<<" "<<points[i].Z()<<endl;
}

qsort( points, 6, sizeof points[0], cmp );

for (int i=0;i<points.size();i++){//after sort
cout<<points[i].X()<<" "<<points[i].Y()<<" "<<points[i].Z()<<endl;
}            
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly easiest to use `std::sort` instead of `qsort`:

```
class Point { 
    int x, y, z;
public:
    Point(int x, int y, int z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

    bool operator<(Point const &other) { 
        return x < other.x;
    }
    // skipping the reading and other stuff for now...
};

int main() { 
    std::vector<Point> points;
    // add some Points to `points` here.

    // sort using order defined in Point::operator<:
    std::sort(points.begin(), points.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: to keep the comparison separate from the items being compared, you use a separate function or functor to do the comparison, and pass that to `std::sort`. There are a few things about your class that you really want to change in any case though -- at the very least, since your `Point::X()`, `Point::Y()` and `Point::Z()` don't modify the Point object, you want to make them `const` member functions. Once you've done that, the sorting is fairly trivial:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

class Point { 
    double x, y, z;
public:
    double X() const { return x; }
    double Y() const { return y; }
    double Z() const { return z; }

    Point(double x=0.0, double y=0.0, double z=0.0) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
};

namespace std { 
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, Point const &p) { 
    return os << "(" << p.X() << ", " << p.Y() << ", " << p.Z() << ")";
}
}
struct byX { 
    bool operator()(Point const &a, Point const &b) { 
        return a.X() < b.X();
    }
};

int main(){ 
    std::vector<Point> points;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        points.push_back(Point(rand(), i, i));

    std::cout << "Unsorted:\n";
    std::copy(points.begin(), points.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<Point>(std::cout, "\n"));

    std::sort(points.begin(), points.end(), byX());

    std::cout << "\nSorted:\n";
    std::copy(points.begin(), points.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<Point>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

Technically, I suppose I should add one more minor detail: if the `x` value in any of your points is a NaN, this won't work correctly. A NaN isn't equal to anything (not even itself) which violates the strict weak ordering required for `std::sort`.

Comment: Good reply.  Please edit to show use of `std::sort` and a function that compares `Point` objects.  This will allow the OP to use different ordering schemes without changing the `Point` class each time. :-)

Comment: @Thomas: At least IMO, that's not such a great idea. The question indicates interest *only* in one ordering; IMO, adding others would confuse rather than clarify.

Comment: Hi Jerry, thanks for your reply, but I want to do this without change my class Point so tell me the way to do this after entered all my data that's mean in outside of the class Point. thanks

Comment: thanks jerry, In my data set, no any NAN value in x. I was compling the codes which you mentioned above but I got a error message; " ostream_iterator is not a member of 'std' " need your help again to solve this. thanks

Comment: @aki: did you lose the `#include <iterator>` perhaps? That should declare `std::ostream_iterator`.

Comment: thanks for your nice job now it is working. by thw way, i need to know further, why you use const for X,Y,Z when constructing the class Point? is it not possible to use without using const. could you pls give me short explanation on this?

Comment: @aki: Sure. When you have a pointer/reference to a const object, the only member functions you call on that object *must* be declared `const` like that. You normally want to mark all member functions that don't modify the object as `const` so you can use them with `const` objects. Googling for something like `C++ const correctness` should yield more about this.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments of the `cmp` function are actually `const Point *px` in your case. You may not be able to declare them as arguments this way, but you can surely `cast` the void pointers later.

Further reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/).